# Can I store a CSS "theme" as a JSON document in CouchDB? ( and then load it and apply it? )

Tags: jquery, css, json, couchdb

The syntax of CSS is a bit similar to JSON, making me wonder whether I could dynamically load and apply a CSS "theme" from a CouchDB using AJAX.  I know I can already serve a CSS file as an attachment, but if the CSS was an actual document, then it could be updated by users.  There could also be several such documents, like css "themes".  How would that work?  I see 2 problems:

1) how to store the CSS as JSON ( in one big string field, or as a structured document? )

2) how to apply the CSS dynamically.

I have found that using jQuery, I can apply CSS to selected elements, but it doesn't work the same as "normal" CSS because the rules of precedence don't apply -- you simply affect all selected elements each time you call the `.css()` function.  What I really need is a way to load an entire "css file" ( as a document ) and apply the whole thing as if it were a normal css file.

Maybe a `"_show"` function can transform a structured JSON/CSS document into a "normal" CSS string  with standard CSS syntax?  Then i just need to figure out how to "apply" it at run-time.

Appreciate any thoughts, ideas, and relevant links -- thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about `_show` function being a good way to dynamically generate non-json response from CouchDB's documents. As for loading that css, code should look like this:

```
var cssTag = $("head").add("link");
cssTag.attr("rel", "stylesheet");
cssTag.attr("type", "text/css");
cssTag.attr("href", filename);
```

In short, you are adding a `link` tag in the `head`.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. Store the CSS as a big String in CouchDB
2. Create an ajax page that will simply echo the stored data from the database, receiving a dynamic querystring for deciding which file to show. Example: http://example.com/change_css?file=new_style2.css
3. Whenever you need to change the current user's theme, you could remove the old  and just append the new one like `$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com/change_css?file=new_style2.css">')`
4. The browser should automatically load and apply the new CSS.

Not sure if storing this dynamically in CouchDB is the best approach: you can always keep the static files and change them on the fly. Storing the CSS as a Json, on the other hand, will require parsing and could be potentially time consumig.